# C++ inherit default operation in function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, overriding

Suppose I have an abstract base class called `Base` and it inherits the other class called `Rectangle` (w/c has the attributes of x, y, w, h)

```
//Base.h

class Base abstract : public Rectangle
{
public:

    Base();

    void Show()
    {

        if (!visible) return;

        //draw the stuff here.

    }

    virtual void PerformTask() = 0;

protected:

    bool visible;
    bool enable;
    //other member variables

};
```

For all the class that inherits this `Base`, it must implement this short operation first:

```
void OtherClass1::PerformTask()
{

    if (!enable) return; // <- this one I am referring to.

    //else, proceed with the overriden operation

    //...
}
```

in `PerformTask()`, could it make a default operation, as I will not retype it again in all its implementation but, at the same time, is overriden and the `short operation` is executed first and preserved?

Comment: Then don't make `Base::PerformTask` pure virtual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this can be done; simply make `PerformTask` a non-virtual function which calls the *actual* overridden function:

```
// In Base:
void PerformTask() {
    if (not enabled) return;

    PerformTaskImpl();
}

virtual void PerformTaskImpl() = 0;
```

… and then just override `PerformTaskImpl` in the derived classes.

This is actually a pretty common pattern.

Comment: How do I know if that `short operation` is executed first before others?

Comment: @mr5 Sorry I don’t understand the question.

Comment: I mean the only thing that will not be overriden is the `short operation` and will be preserved for every class that inherits it.